# Javascript date undefined error

Tags: javascript

this is my code and I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" what am i doing wrong?

```
var myDate = new Date().setDate(17);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myDate.getDate();
```

Comment: .. and why redefine `somethingelse` when it is not used the first time?

Comment: The third var is useless. You only need to declare a variable once, as you've already done with the second var.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setDate` *modifies* the object it is called on and returns `undefined`. If you want to make `somethingelse` refer to the date that `today` referred to, but changing the day, you could copy `today` and then change `somethingelse`:

```
var today = new Date();
var somethingelse = new Date(today.getTime());
somethingelse.setDate(17);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = somethingelse.getDate();
```

Of course, if you didn’t care about preserving what was in `today`, you could certainly modify that without creating a copy.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(17);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = date.getDate();
```

Comment: `new Date(today)` will convert *today* to a string, then parse the string back to a Date, consider `new Date(+today)` which is equivalent to using `today.getTime()` but less to type. ;-) Note also that for a date like 21 January, 15 the above method will copy the date as 21 January, 1915 in IE and some other browsers. An obscure legacy of 2 digit years, but one of those things that will bite somebody sometime…

Answer (score 2):

This much is enough: You can take the same `today` object and `set` and `get` date for that object.

```
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(17);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = today.getDate();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzpp2cs7/)